# Error with powerdot: Wrong DVI mode driver option

Tags: errors, powerdot

I have used LaTeX for a while but I normally used templates from the internet. Now I am trying to use one from a professor and I can not get it to compile. The code is:

```
\documentclass[size=11pt, style=fyma]{powerdot}

\usepackage{amsmath,amstext,amssymb,latexsym}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node,pstricks-add}

\usepackage{graphicx}
```

And the error I get is:

```
Package hyperref Error: wrong DVI mode driver option 'dvips', (hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.
```

Can anyone tell how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Please add a compilable MWE and add which engine (or tools) you use to compile.

Comment: Sorry but I do not know what MWE is. I am trying to compile using LaTeX.

Comment: You can't use powerdot with pdflatex. Use latex + dvips instead (and remove auto-pst-pdf)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have removed that one. Where should I write latex+dvips? Or where do I select that?

Comment: How should I know how you can call latex? You neither said what texsystem nor which editor nor which OS you are using. Btw: In case you are using a current miktex check this bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2577/

Comment: I am using TeXShop as an editor and my operative system is macOS.

Comment: texshop has imho a dropdown menu where you can choose latex instead of pdflatex for compilation. And it certainly has some button or menu entry for dvips.

Comment: Ah! Great. Thank you so much. And sorry for being so slow understanding! It's working now. Thank you very very much!